# Index was outside the bounds of the array visual basics

Tags: arrays, indexing, bounds

I am having this error that my index was outside the bounds of the array.
Could anyone help me look at my code please?

```
Private Sub picList_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles picList.Click
    frmList.Show()
    frmList.lstShow.Items.Clear()
    Dim fmtStr As String = "{0,-5}{1,-10}{2,-15}{3,-20}{4,-25}"
    With frmList.lstShow.Items
        .Add(String.Format(fmtStr, "University Name", "Abbreviation", "State", "Accredited Year", "Total Students"))
        For A = 0 To N - 1
            .Add(String.Format(fmtStr, Name(A), Abbreviation(A), State(A), Accredited(A), Total(A)))
        Next
        .Add(String.Format(fmtStr, "", "", "", "", ""))
        .Add("Total of " & N & " Universities.")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: On which line is the exception thrown?  What values to the variables have at that point?

Comment: What are the UBounds of Name, Abbreviation, State, Accreditation, and Total?